# div and ion-list removed the col-6 effect on the grid

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, ionic3

Below code is working fine.

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
 <ion-grid no-padding>
   <ion-row class="row3">
   <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">
     <presentation [data]="d"></presentation>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
.content {
        ion-grid {
            height: 40%;
        }
        .row1 {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            .searchbar {
                padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            }
        }
        .row2 {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .row3 {
            .col * {
                padding: 0 10px 10px 5px;
            }
            flex: 2;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        [col-1] {
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 30%;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Renderd on Browser*

[image]

*UI 1:*

[image]

I have changed it like this.Only `HTML` code.I have just introduced this 2 lines.

```
  <div [ngSwitch]="pet">
            <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'kittens'">
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
 <ion-row class="row3">
      <div [ngSwitch]="pet">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'kittens'">
          <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">
            <presentation [data]="d"></presentation>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-list>
      </div> 
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*Now rendered on Browser*

[image]

*UI 2:*

[image]

You can see that, now there is no `col-6` effect.Can you help me to reinstate it back? In other words same as on the first use case.

When I replaced it with `div` it shows as below.It brakes `col-6` now.But I need 2 columns.Any trick?

```
 <ion-row class="row3">
      <div [ngSwitch]="pet">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'kittens'">
          <div col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">
            <presentation [data]="d"></presentation>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-row>
```

*UI 3:*

[image]

Comment: any reason you are mixing `ion-list` with `ion-col`? maybe try `div` instead?

Comment: Please see the last part of my post.Now it brakes nicely.But only one column.Do you know how to have 2 columns? @suraj

Comment: did you try putting the whole grid within the switch?

Comment: @suraj I cannot do that hence other rows are having different data.On this row where I'm going to implement Segment using this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#segment

Comment: you seem to be using `div` instead of `ion-col`..

Comment: You mean without `Ionic grid`? @suraj

Comment: check your last updated code.. you have `<div col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">` use `ion-col`

Comment: Yes, I tried that.But no break when `col-6` then.Same UI as my `UI 2` image above.@suraj

Comment: Try adding `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap` to your ion-list or add `float:left` to your items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, I think there is a problem with the HTML element nesting (between `ion-row` and `ion-col`). Because of that, the styles are not applying correctly for the `ion-col`.

Try changing your HTML as follows:

```
<ion-row class="row3">
    <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">
        <div [ngSwitch]="pet">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'kittens'">
                <presentation [data]="d"></presentation>
            </div>
            <!-- other ngSwitchCases -->
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

---

Cheers!